# Will not proceed with macro for #N/A cell

Tags: vba, excel-2010, vlookup

I have a VBA/ Macro code that performs a few task.  It looks up a file based on column E and will open that file and copy range A8:C8 into the master workbook.  My biggest issue is when it comes to #N/A values for the file names.  Column E is a lookup of a master list to find the name of the file. If it cant find it, a #N/A is placed in Column E.  I have tried to skip the error and change it from value to text but neither have worked.  Can someone please help with skipping the #N/A values and resuming the code?

```
Sub CopyFromClosedWorkbook()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim varCellvalue As Variant
Dim i As Long


For i = 2 To 20

varCellvalue = Range("E" & i).Value

' Disable screen updating to reduce screen flicker
Application.ScreenUpdating = False




' Define which workbook is which
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("S:\Shoppw\PkgSpc\" & varCellvalue & ".xls")


If Not IsError(varCellvalue) Then

' Copy range A1:W70 from the Data sheet of wb2
wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A8:C8").Copy
' Paste the copied data to range A1 of the Data sheet in wb1
wb1.Sheets("WeightList").Range("F" & i).PasteSpecial

' Close wb2
wb2.Close



' Re-enable screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End If

Next i




End Sub
```

Comment: `If Not IsError(varCellvalue) Then`...

Comment: `Dim varCellvalue As Variant`. If varCellvalue is String then `varCellvalue = Range("E" & i).Value` will cause Type mismatch error when #N/A in the cell.

Comment: @Алексей Р Changing it to a variant still produced the same error.

Comment: @Tara did you take into account both of the tips above?

Comment: Yes I still get the mismatch

Comment: Move `If Not IsError(varCellvalue) Then` before `Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("S:\Shoppw\PkgSpc\" & varCellvalue & ".xls")`

Comment: It worked! I used both of your comments and added back the if error resume next and that cleared it up. Thanks for your help!